# Jekyll serve suddenly switched from localhost to 0.0.0.0 - any fix?

Tags: jekyll

When using Jekyll command 'Jekyll serve', the local url switched from `http ://localhost:4000/` to `http ://0.0.0.0:4000/` - it was working fine, not sure what would have changed?

Any suggestions for getting back to the original config?

Mac OS 10.9.3, RVM Ruby 2.1.2

I've read some posts where users originally got hit with `0.0.0.0` - but my initial install was working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

The [default configuration](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#default-configuration) changed.

Use `jekyll serve --host localhost` or set `host: localhost` in _config.yml

Answer (score 12):

In `_config.yml`

```
# deployment
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 5000
```

This can change host and port.